# python filenames encoded wrong

Tags: python, character-encoding, raspberry-pi, filenames

I've got some python 2.7.3 code on the Raspberry Pi B+ that loops and creates some dummy files. Unfortunately, the filenames get garbled somewhere between python and the filesystem.

```
    settime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    for n in range(int(setlength)):
        time.sleep(GetShutterSpeed(shutter))
        image = 'img/'
        image += settime
        image += shutter + ' '
        image += 'ISO' + iso
        image += ' #' + str(n+1).rjust(len(setlength), '0')
        image += ' of ' + setlength
        image += '.jpg'
        with open(image, 'w') as f:
            f.write('')
        ro(strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ' > ' + image)
```

Here's what I get when I browse to where the images are saved from a windows share over samba.

[image]

**Why are these files named so strangely?**

Is this because I'm trying to save text files named as .jpgs? Or am I messing up the character encoding somewhere? I don't have any problems opening files in the same python code that already exist. I tried removing the `#`s, but that didn't matter. If I pass in a `/`, it balks completely, which is as expected. Just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with the filename itself.

Comment: You have several undefined values in your code snippet. Please create the shortest possible *complete* program that demonstrates the error. Please copy-paste that short complete program into your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: What are those filenames, then? Everything in the right hand side of the screenshot? If so then Windows refuses these names for lots of reasons, all of which can be summarized with "invalid character in filename".

Comment: remove > : and # from file names.